# Cannot convert value of type [Type] to expected argument type 'some View'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got the following struct:

```
struct A : View {

    var backgroundView: some View = Color.white

    var body = some View {
        VStack {
            Text("abc")
        }
        .background(backgroundView)
    }

}
```

This works fine in preview, as long as I am not specifying my own `backgroundView`:

```
struct A_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        A()
    }
}
```

But when I specify the backgroundView to e.g. a LinearGradient:

```
struct A_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        A(backgroundView: LinearGradient(
             gradient: Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .white]),
             startPoint: .bottom,
             endPoint: .top))
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'LinearGradient' to expected argument type 'some View'

Why does the default implementation work and why doesn't the custom declaration do? How can I set up a prameter that can accept both Color and LinearGradient types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to solve is using `AnyView` and wrapping the values inside it: based on this article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-return-different-view-types

```
struct A : View {

    var backgroundView: AnyView = AnyView(Color.white)

    var body = some View {
        VStack {
            Text("abc")
        }
        .background(backgroundView)
    }

}
```

And then:

```
struct A_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        A(backgroundView: AnyView(LinearGradient(
             gradient: Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .white]),
             startPoint: .bottom,
             endPoint: .top)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use genericity. `View` contains reference to `Self` that's why you can't use it the way you wanted.

Try something like that :

```
struct A<BackgroundView : View> : View {

    var backgroundView: BackgroundView

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text("abc")
        }
        .background(backgroundView)
    }

}

struct A_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        A(backgroundView: LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .white]),
            startPoint: .bottom,
            endPoint: .top))
    }
}
```

And if you still need your default implementation, you can just add something like:

```
let defaultA = A(backgroundView: Color.white)

struct A_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        defaultA
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not good because if I have let's say 5 optional parameters that have default values, then I need to create 32 lines of `let defaultA = ...` to cover every case when they are modified or stayed the default value. Not to mention the 5 generic type parameter. My biggest issue is that `Color`-type values can be given as arguments to the `.background()` method, and so can `LinearGradient`-type values, yet there is no variable type which I can specify that will accept both and is also a valid variable type for the `.background()` method.

Comment: I want this to be a very flexible framework, where users customize as many things as they want

Comment: Tricky problem indeed, because with genericity (the way SwiftUI has been designed) the customization "by default" is not that obvious... If I come with a solution I'll let you know... But maybe you'll need to rethink your model to match SwiftUI philosophy.

Comment: My final solution is wrapping them in an `AnyView`. That way both is valid value for the property.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in the following way (tested on Xcode 11.2):

```
// Declarations >>>
struct A<Background> : View where Background : View {

    var backgroundView: Background

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("abc")
            }
            .background(backgroundView)
        }
    }

}

extension A where Background == Color {
    static var `default`: A<Color> {
        A<Color>(backgroundView: Color.white)
    }
}

// Testing >>>

struct TestSomeViewUsage: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            A.default
            Divider()
            A(backgroundView: LinearGradient(
                 gradient: Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .white]),
                 startPoint: .bottom,
                 endPoint: .top))
        }
    }
}

struct TestSomeViewUsage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestSomeViewUsage()
    }
}
```